# Is there a way to perform animations between activities?

Tags: android

I was wandering whether there is a way to perform 
animations between activities like you see when you press the search in google maps (it slides down from the top).
From my research I have gathered it us only possible been views. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formal way is `overridePendingTransition` but is available to API level >= 5 a.k.a android 2.0

you can .. check [this](http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/26/android-switching-screens-in-an-activity-with-animations-using-viewflipper/) out using viewflipper to switch , but is't not seperate activities

Comment: Also note that the user has the ability to toggle off these inter-activity animations (default or any of your overrides), AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks I am using 1.6 but guess I could use reflection for this.

Comment: Or maybe it isn't available for me to override because I am on 1.6?